# SKPhysicsBody net force taken by objects?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Basically I want to give a physicsBody "health" and when it gets hit I want to decrease that health dynamically. If it gets hit hard, I want to take away a lot of health.

I know how to give the node the health and take away from that value using Node.userData, but I don't know how to detect the force of an impact.

I also know you can detect an "impact" with CGRectIntersectsRect but that doesn't return a magnitude obviously, as it is a method of the node not the physicsBody..

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `didBeginContact:` you get a [SKPhysicsContact](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsContact/collisionImpulse) object which contains a `collisionImpulse` property:

> The impulse that specifies how hard these two bodies struck each other
>   in newton-seconds.

The `didBeginContact:` message is received by the `SKPhysicsWorld`'s delegate (`SKPhysicsContactDelegate`).

Comment: You're my hero... Thanks